# Add iOS Unit test target in Xcode project using CMake

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

Is it possible nowadays to create an Xcode iOS unit test target from CMake? I've read this [5 years old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829642/can-i-create-an-ios-unit-test-target-for-xcode-ocunit-with-cmake) but I hope this was added in a later version of CMake.

If the answer is positive, could you please provide an example?